# Attaching Closure to UIButton (To design custom popup)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, closures, alert

I would like to know, how I can attach a closure to a UIButton embedded in a xib file.
I already saw some answer on SO that are not working for me (like making an UIButton Extension)

Here is my Popup file that implement the popup

```
import UIKit

class Popup: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!
    // Our custom view from the XIB file
    var view: UIView!

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds

        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "Popup", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(frame:)
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(coder:)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

    func fill(_ title : String, _ message : String, _ left : String, _ right : String){
        self.titleLabel.text = title.uppercased()
        self.messageLabel.text = message
        self.leftButton.setTitle(left, for: .normal)
        self.rightButton.setTitle(right, for: .normal)
    }

    func addTouch(_ leftAction : () -> ()){
        let action1 = Action { print("iouiou") }
        self.leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action1.action), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

}

final class Action: NSObject {

    private let _action: () -> ()

    init(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
        _action = action
        super.init()
    }

    func action() {
        _action()
    }

}
```

And here is how I create that popup

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let popup = Popup(frame: self.view.frame)
        popup.fill("Titre", "Message", "Left", "Right")
        popup.addTouch({ 
            print("blah")
        })
        self.view.addSubview(popup)
    }

}
```

At this point I got this error when I tap the button which is supposed to perform the closure

```
2017-05-17 10:03:03.573 alert[32840:1427675] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[alert.Popup action]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8916e024a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109927b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106bce141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109997134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098ae840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098ae3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001070a1d22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010722625c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107226577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001072254b2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010710f49a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107110bb0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001070bd7b0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001078a0adc __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107898a3a __handleEventQueue + 1122
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098cdc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098b30cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098b25ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098b2016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b832a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001070a00d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  alert                               0x00000001065de207 main + 55
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a8c765d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few Issues... 
1. action1 can't be local variable, Make it class variable 
2. adding target to button is wrongly done.

Try this, I have fixed the issues...

```
final class Action: NSObject {        
    private let _action: () -> ()        
    init(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
        _action = action
        super.init()
    }

    func action() {
        _action()
    }
}
```

Popup View

```
class Popup: UIView {        
    //... your other code        

    var action1:Action?        
    func addTouch(_ leftAction : @escaping () -> ()){
        action1 = Action.init(action: leftAction)
        self.leftButton.addTarget(action1, action: #selector(Action.action), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yaaaay ! Thanks a lot ! It works ! 
However what do you advise instead of adding target to button ?

Comment: You were adding the wrong target and selector... Target is the object going to receive the action and selector is the method signature... In your case  `action1` is target and `Action.action` is the selector... See my code how i have done it.

Comment: Aw ok ! Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Your variable action1 is a local variable to your addAction() function. It is getting deleted as soon as you leave the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to put this action1 as global variable, but in the end, the same error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
open class Button: UIButton {
  
  private var action: (() -> Void)?
  
  public func perform(for event: UIControl.Event = .touchUpInside, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.action = action
    addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionToPerform), for: event)
  }

  // MARK: - Helpers
  
  @objc private func actionToPerform() {
    action?()
  }
}
```

Use it:

```
class Popup: UIView { 

    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: Button!
       
    // code...

    self.leftButton.perform {
      print("Your action.")
    }
}
```